# Zend Select "where IN (?)" filter returning results that are NOT IN

Tags: mysql, resource-model, zend-framework, select

I am working on a segmented version of Magento's Invoiced Totals report. Currently without my additional filters the report reflects what Magento's Core report shows, good.

I am trying to add a condition that will narrow the results to orders whose customer_email column is in a customer email list. In the resource below I have added...

```
    if ($getRegisteredBusinessData == true):
        $businessAccounts = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getRegisteredBusinessAccounts();
        $businessEmailList = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getAccountsEmailsArr($businessAccounts);
        $select->where('customer_email IN (?)', $businessEmailList);
        //echo $filterSubSelect->__toString(); die;
    endif;
```

Basically this interprets to `$businessEmailList = ["email@1.com",email@2.com]` and the filter being `$select->where('customer_email IN (?), $businessEmailList);`

My problem is what my results include orders that are not in my $businessEmailList array.

**Full Resource:**

```
/**
 * Aggregate Invoiced data by invoice created_at as period
 *
 * @param mixed $from
 * @param mixed $to
 * @return Etre_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Segment_Invoiced
 */
protected function _aggregateByInvoiceCreatedAt($from, $to, $segmentId = 0)
{
    $table = $this->getTable('etre_reports/segmented_invoiced_aggregated');
    $sourceTable = $this->getTable('sales/invoice');
    $orderTable = $this->getTable('sales/order');
    $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

    $adapter->beginTransaction();

    try {
        if ($from !== null || $to !== null) {
            $subSelect = $this->_getTableDateRangeRelatedSelect(
                $sourceTable, $orderTable, array('order_id' => 'entity_id'),
                'created_at', 'updated_at', $from, $to
            );
        } else {
            $subSelect = null;
        }

        $this->_clearTableByDateRange($table, $from, $to, $subSelect);
        // convert dates from UTC to current admin timezone
        $periodExpr = $adapter->getDatePartSql(
            $this->getStoreTZOffsetQuery(
                array('source_table' => $sourceTable),
                'source_table.created_at', $from, $to
            )
        );
        $columns = array(
            // convert dates from UTC to current admin timezone
            'segment_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr($segmentId), /* Magento expects to find these values in the sales_order table - work around or add segment id to ALL orders :/ */
            'increment_ids' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(source_table.increment_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
            'period' => $periodExpr,
            'store_id' => 'order_table.store_id',
            'order_status' => 'order_table.status',
            'orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(order_table.entity_id)'),
            'orders_invoiced' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(order_table.entity_id)'),
            'invoiced' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(order_table.base_total_invoiced'
                . ' * order_table.base_to_global_rate)'),
            'invoiced_captured' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(order_table.base_total_paid'
                . ' * order_table.base_to_global_rate)'),
            'invoiced_not_captured' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                'SUM((order_table.base_total_invoiced - order_table.base_total_paid)'
                . ' * order_table.base_to_global_rate)')
        );

        $select = $adapter->select();
        $select->from(array('source_table' => $sourceTable), $columns)
            ->joinInner(
                array('order_table' => $orderTable),
                $adapter->quoteInto(
                    'source_table.order_id = order_table.entity_id AND order_table.state <> ?',
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED),
                array()
            );
        $filterSubSelect = $adapter->select();
        $getRegisteredBusinessData = true;
        $filterSubSelect->from(array('filter_source_table' => $sourceTable), 'MAX(filter_source_table.entity_id)')
            ->where('filter_source_table.order_id = source_table.order_id');

        if ($subSelect !== null) {
            $select->having($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
        }

        $select->where('source_table.entity_id = (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr($filterSubSelect));

        if ($getRegisteredBusinessData == true):
            $businessAccounts = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getRegisteredBusinessAccounts();
            $businessEmailList = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getAccountsEmailsArr($businessAccounts);
            $select->where('customer_email IN (?)', $businessEmailList);
            //echo $filterSubSelect->__toString(); die;
        endif;
        unset($filterSubSelect);

        $adapter->query("SET group_concat_max_len = {$this->ordersAllowedInMysqlConcat()}");
        $select->group(array(
            $periodExpr,
            'order_table.store_id',
            'order_table.status'
        ));

        $select->having('orders_count > 0');
        zend_debug::dump($adapter->fetchAssoc($select));
        die;
        unset($columns['increment_ids']);
        $insertQuery = $helper->getInsertFromSelectUsingAnalytic($select, $table, array_keys($columns));
        $adapter->query($insertQuery);
        $select->reset();

        $columns = array(
            'segment_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr($segmentId), /* Magento expects to find these values in the sales_order table - work around or add segment id to ALL orders :/ */
            'period' => 'period',
            'store_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID),
            'order_status' => 'order_status',
            'orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(orders_count)'),
            'orders_invoiced' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(orders_invoiced)'),
            'invoiced' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(invoiced)'),
            'invoiced_captured' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(invoiced_captured)'),
            'invoiced_not_captured' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(invoiced_not_captured)')
        );

        $select
            ->from($table, $columns)
            ->where('store_id <> ?', 0);

        if ($subSelect !== null) {
            $select->where($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
        }

        $select->group(array(
            'period',
            'order_status'
        ));

        $insertQuery = $helper->getInsertFromSelectUsingAnalytic($select, $table, array_keys($columns));
        $adapter->query($insertQuery);
        $adapter->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think output you want put filter in condition but you are missing `$businessEmailList->getSelect()`

```
$businessEmailList = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getAccountsEmailsArr($businessAccounts);
        $businessEmailList->getSelect()->where('customer_email IN (?)', $businessEmailList);
```

or you can add filter like that

```
        $newlist=explode(',',$businessEmailList);
        $businessEmailList = Mage::getModel("etre_reports/customersegmented")->getAccountsEmailsArr($businessAccounts);
          $businessEmailList->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('in'=>$newlist)));
```

Comment: Well, I have two different queries. One creates my `$businessEmailList` array and my other query is in $select, which can be seen in the full function in my original post. I want to add a filter to $select so that the results only include orders created by emails in $businessEmailList. This returns orders that are not in $businessEmailList: `$select->where('customer_email IN (?)', $businessEmailList);`